# Calculate Total value for two input fields based on items selected from a select option tag in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get the value of the **Amount** pass to either **Debit Amount** or **Credit Amount** base on the **Type** selected if **DR** is select, then the value should be pass to **Debit Amount** and if **CR** is selected, then the value should be pass to **Credit Amount**. Total Amount should be passed in case of multiple **Type** options are selected
[image]

**The HTML**

```
<div>
       <label style="margin-bottom:3px;">Debit Amount</label><span>
        <input type="text" name="total_debit" id="totalDebit"/></span>
    </div>
    <div>
    <label>Credit Amount</label><span>
        <input type="text" name="total_credit" id="totalCredit" /></span>
    </div>
<table class="table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
            <th width="2%"><input id="check_all" type="checkbox"/></th>
            <th width="5%">Type</th>
            <th width="5%">Account Code</th>
            <th width="15%">Account Name</th>
            <th width="10%">Fund</th>
            <th width="10%">Amount</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input class="case" type="checkbox"/></td>
        <td><select name="account_id[]" class="   mySelect" id="type_1">
                <option value="000"></option>
                <option value="1">DR</option>
                <option value="2">CR</option>
                </select>
        </td>
        <td>
         <input type="text" name="accountCode[]" id="accountCode_1">
       </td>
       <td>
          <input type="text" name="accountName[]" id="accountName_1"></td>
       <td>
          <select name="fund_id[]" >
            <option></option>
          </select>
       </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text"  name="amount[]" id="amount_1" class="totalLineAmount">
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input class="case" type="checkbox"/></td>
        <td><select name="account_id[]" class="   mySelect" id="type_2">
                <option value="000"></option>
                <option value="1">DR</option>
                <option value="2">CR</option>
                </select>
        </td>
        <td>
         <input type="text" name="accountCode[]" id="accountCode_2">
       </td>
       <td>
          <input type="text" name="accountName[]" id="accountName_2"></td>
       <td>
          <select name="fund_id[]" >
            <option></option>
          </select>
       </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text"  name="amount[]" id="amount_2" class="totalLineAmount">
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input class="case" type="checkbox"/></td>
        <td><select name="account_id[]" class="   mySelect" id="type_3">
                <option value="000"></option>
                <option value="1">DR</option>
                <option value="2">CR</option>
                </select>
        </td>
        <td>
         <input type="text" name="accountCode[]" id="accountCode_3">
       </td>
       <td>
          <input type="text" name="accountName[]" id="accountName_3"></td>
       <td>
          <select name="fund_id[]" >
            <option></option>
          </select>
       </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text"  name="amount[]" id="amount_3" class="totalLineAmount">
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input class="case" type="checkbox"/></td>
        <td><select name="account_id[]" class="   mySelect" id="type_4">
                <option value="000"></option>
                <option value="1">DR</option>
                <option value="2">CR</option>
                </select>
        </td>
        <td>
         <input type="text" name="accountCode[]" id="accountCode_4">
       </td>
       <td>
          <input type="text" name="accountName[]" id="accountName_4"></td>
       <td>
          <select name="fund_id[]" >
            <option></option>
          </select>
       </td>
        <td>
    <input type="text"  name="amount[]" id="amount_4" class="totalLineAmount">
        </td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

**Jquery Script**

```
  <script>
$(function(){
  $(document).on("change",".mySelect",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var _this=$(this);
    var id =_this.val();
    if ( id == 1) {
        calculateTotalDebit();
    }else if (id == 2) {
   calculateTotalCredit();
    }

function calculateTotalDebit(){
    total = 0;
    $('.totalLineAmount').each(function(){

        if($(this).val() != '' )total += parseFloat( $(this).val() );
        $('#totalDebit').val( total.toFixed(2) );
    });


}    

 function calculateTotalCredit(){
    total = 0;
    $('.totalLineAmount').each(function(){
        if($(this).val() != '' )total += parseFloat( $(this).val() );
    });

    $('#totalCredit').val( total.toFixed(2) );
    }   
  });

});
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('.totalLineAmount')` is selecting all of the amount inputs, so the `calculateTotalDebit` and `calculateTotalCredit` functions are adding them all regardless of the DR/CR type. You can check for the type inside the functions, for `calculateTotalDebit` for example:

```
function calculateTotalDebit(){
var total = 0;
$('.totalLineAmount').each(function(){
    var thisNumber = $(this).attr('id').slice(-1);
    // select the type of this amount
    var type = $('#type_' + thisNumber);
    // add only if the type is DR (val == 1)
    if($(this).val() != '' && type.val() == 1)total += parseFloat( $(this).val() );
    $('#totalDebit').val( total.toFixed(2) );
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on("change", ".mySelect", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var _this = $(this);
    var id = _this.val();
    if (id == 1) {
      calculateTotalDebit();
    } else if (id == 2) {
      calculateTotalCredit();
    }

    function calculateTotalDebit() {
      total = 0;
      $('.totalLineAmount').each(function() {
        var thisNumber = $(this).attr('id').slice(-1);
        // select the type of this amount
        var type = $('#type_' + thisNumber);
        // add only if the type is DR (val == 1)
        if ($(this).val() != '' && type.val() == 1) total += parseFloat($(this).val());
        $('#totalDebit').val(total.toFixed(2));
      });


    }

    function calculateTotalCredit() {
      total = 0;
      $('.totalLineAmount').each(function() {
        var thisNumber = $(this).attr('id').slice(-1);
        // select the type of this amount
        var type = $('#type_' + thisNumber);
        // add only if the type is CR (val == 2)
        if ($(this).val() != '' && type.val() == 2) total += parseFloat($(this).val());
      });

      $('#totalCredit').val(total.toFixed(2));
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label style="margin-bottom:3px;">Debit Amount</label><span>
        <input type="text" name="total_debit" id="totalDebit"/></span>
</div>
<div>
  <label>Credit Amount</label><span>
        <input type="text" name="total_credit" id="totalCredit" /></span>
</div>
<table class="table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="2%">
        <input id="check_all" type="checkbox" />
      </th>
      <th width="5%">Type</th>
      <th width="5%">Account Code</th>
      <th width="15%">Account Name</th>
      <th width="10%">Fund</th>
      <th width="10%">Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="case" type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="account_id[]" class="   mySelect" id="type_1">
          <option value="000"></option>
          <option value="1">DR</option>
          <option value="2">CR</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="accountCode[]" id="accountCode_1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="accountName[]" id="accountName_1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="fund_id[]">
          <option></option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="amount[]" id="amount_1" class="totalLineAmount">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="case" type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="account_id[]" class="   mySelect" id="type_2">
          <option value="000"></option>
          <option value="1">DR</option>
          <option value="2">CR</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="accountCode[]" id="accountCode_2">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="accountName[]" id="accountName_2">
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="fund_id[]">
          <option></option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="amount[]" id="amount_2" class="totalLineAmount">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="case" type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="account_id[]" class="   mySelect" id="type_3">
          <option value="000"></option>
          <option value="1">DR</option>
          <option value="2">CR</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="accountCode[]" id="accountCode_3">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="accountName[]" id="accountName_3">
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="fund_id[]">
          <option></option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="amount[]" id="amount_3" class="totalLineAmount">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="case" type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="account_id[]" class="   mySelect" id="type_4">
          <option value="000"></option>
          <option value="1">DR</option>
          <option value="2">CR</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="accountCode[]" id="accountCode_4">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="accountName[]" id="accountName_4">
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="fund_id[]">
          <option></option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="amount[]" id="amount_4" class="totalLineAmount">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I guess you have to update both "Debit Amount" and "Credit Amount" boxes, so you have to call both functions each time. It may be better to merge both functions into one `calculateAmounts` function. I'd also add event listeners to the `.totalLineAmount` boxes to update the totals automatically.

Comment: I want to pass the value (the last cell in each row) to either Debit Amount or Credit Amount at the top base on the Type. That is if DR is selected, the corresponding amount value in that row should be pass to Debit Amount and vice versa. My function works but it does not separate DR corresponding amount to Debit Amount but it passes the total in the Amount column irrespective of the Type selected

Comment: @AbdulSuadikMohammed Edited

Comment: Thanks, Am very grateful

Answer (score 1):

Try this code instead ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/koghccgn/)):

```
$(function() {
  function calculateTotals() {
    var DRTotal = 0,
      CRTotal = 0;
    $('.totalLineAmount').each(function() {
      var $this = $(this),
        val = $this.val() || 0,
        type = $this.closest('tr').find('.mySelect').val();
      if (val && type === "1") {
        DRTotal += parseFloat(val);
      } else if (val && type === "2") {
        CRTotal += parseFloat(val);
      }
    });
    $('#totalDebit').val(DRTotal.toFixed(2));
    $('#totalCredit').val(CRTotal.toFixed(2));
  }

  $(document).on("change", ".mySelect, .totalLineAmount", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    calculateTotals();
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should add event listener on each input, calculate and put proper data into total amount in your callback function like

```
$('.myInputClass').on('change', function() {
    // your code here..
    updateAmountField(amount);
});

function updateAmountField(amount) {
    $('.myTotalAmountInput').value(amount);
}
```

Comment: please check the code I posted. I did similar but its not working. Thanks